# How can I wait for the XHR request end if is inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I've read many answers but I don't understand in this case how I can solve this problem.

I have an array of points and with an external website I can determine if the point is on land or on sea. The problem is that the `for` loop doesn't wait for the XHR request.

```
var points = [
  [90, 120],
  [80, 120],
  [70, 120]
];

var land_or_sea = [];
for(var x= 0; x < points.length; x++) {
  var lat_string = points[x][0];
  var lng_string = points[x][1];

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){                  
      var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);          
        if (obj.water === true){
          land_or_sea.push(x + 1);                      
        }                           
     }
   }
   xhr.open("GET", "https://api.onwater.io/api/v1/results/" + lat_string + "," + lng_string, true);
   xhr.send();
}
```

How can you see `land_or_sea` is an empty array when I should add index of `points` if point is on sea but doesn't work because for loop doesn't wait.

I hope that can you help me. Thanks!

Comment: I know this mind sound like a bad answer, but I was in your place once and wanted to use synchronous calls everywhere. Learning how to work with promises helped me immensely. At first it is weird, but when you wrap your head around this new way of coding it all makes sense. Here are some links that may be helpful: [promises](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/master-the-javascript-interview-what-is-a-promise-27fc71e77261), [more promises](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies)

Answer (score 1):

I think your best move is to avoid so much api requests and create one api request that will handle list of coordinates. But i guess this api doesn't support it.

Did you check if the api works ok, since i tried and it gave me one false for water, one null and one 500 error telling me too much requests error.

Another good thing is to use xhr.onload method since you have a problem for each time you move through the function defined for onreadystatechange your x variable increments until 3, so for every subsequent readystatechange (for example final response) you are kept with x = 3, since closure keeps pointer, not a value in time of definition. So if this works it will fill the array with value 4 since you put x + 1 like [4, 4, 4].

To wrap it up, use onload and not onreadystatechange and keep an eye on 429/500 errors. Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried your code but doesn't work.... maybe i'm not a good programmer like you :/

Comment: i've updated the comment, hope it's much clearer now

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a for loop, you can create a recursive function.

You can initialize the array index to 0 and pass it to the function. After successful response, call the same function again with incremented array index. Stop calling the function once you reach `array.length`

eg:

```
var points = [
  [90, 120],
  [80, 120],
  [70, 120]
];

var arrIndex = 0;
var land_or_sea = [];

function callAjaxFunc(arrIndex){
  var lat_string = points[arrIndex][0];
  var lng_string = points[arrIndex][1];

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){                  
      var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);          
        if (obj.water === true){
          land_or_sea.push(x + 1);    
          if (arrIndex < points.length){
            arrIndex++;
            callAjaxFunc(arrIndex);
          }    
        }                           
     }
   }
   xhr.open("GET", "https://api.onwater.io/api/v1/results/" + lat_string + "," + lng_string, true);
   xhr.send();
}
callAjaxFunc(arrIndex);
```

Comment: i tried many times your code event change something but nothing doesn't work... :/

Answer (score 0):

If you have ES7 support you can wrap your entire code inside an asynchronous function and just await the result. Create a promise and use it like this: (again, *this only applies if you support ES7*)

```
   (async () => {
var points = [
  [90, 120],
  [80, 120],
  [70, 120]
];

var p = (lat_string, lng_string) => new Promise(res => {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){                  
      res(JSON.parse(this.responseText));            
     }
   }
   xhr.open("GET", "https://api.onwater.io/api/v1/results/" + lat_string + "," + lng_string, true);
   xhr.send();
})

var land_or_sea = [];
for(var x= 0; x < points.length; x++) {
  var lat_string = points[x][0];
  var lng_string = points[x][1];
  var obj = await p(lat_string, lng_string)
  if(obj.water === true) {
    land_or_sea.push(x + 1);                      
  }                       
}
})()
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is a Synchrounous xhr request.

The XMLHttpRequest.open() method full syntax is as follows:

```
XMLHttpRequest.open(method, url, async, user, password)
```

You can set the "async" request parameter to "false".  If this value is false, the send() method does not return until the response is received.

Comment: You tried: xhr.open("GET", "https://api.onwater.io/api/v1/results/" + lat_string + "," + lng_string, false); And it still doesn't work?

Comment: yes work but it slows down considerably...so is not a good idea

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18796649)

Comment: @MukulKant you are right. I have edited my answer. Thank you for correctly pointing that out